# Spring Boot Not working with Spring data cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

I have a spring-boot application and i am trying to connect to the cassandra database using spring-data-cassandra. Below are my files.

**SampleApp.java**

```
package com.spring.sample;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
    import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.spring.sample"})
    @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.spring.sample"})
    @Import(CassandraDataSourceConfig.class)
    public class SampleApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(SampleApp.class);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(SampleApp.class, args);
        }

    }
```

**CassandraDataSourceConfig.java**

```
package com.spring.sample;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;


    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
    @EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.spring.sample"})
    public class CassandraDataSourceConfig {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @Bean
        public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
            CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
            cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
            cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
            // cluster.setContactPoints("localhost");
            // cluster.setPort(9042);
            return cluster;
        }

        @Bean
        public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
            return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
        }

        @Bean
        public CassandraConverter converter() {
            return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
        }

        @Bean
        public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

            CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
            session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
            session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
            session.setConverter(converter());
            session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

            return session;
        }

        @Bean
        public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
            return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
        }

    /*
        @Bean
        public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
            return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
        }


        @Override
        protected String getKeyspaceName() {

            //return environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace");
            return "sample";
        }  */


    }
```

**Properties file**

```
cassandra.contactpoints=127.0.0.1
cassandra.port=9042
cassandra.keyspace=sample
```

Below is the exception i am getting when i try to start the app using embedded tomcat server (mvn spring-boot:run). The app fails to load complaining that **Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource** . But, i am clearly importing the CassandraDataSourceConfig.java in the main app file(SampleApp.java). Can someone help.? Why is the app failing to recognize CassandraDataSourceConfig.java as a valid data source.? Do i have to do something special for integrating spring-data-cassandra with spring-boot.?? Thanks in advance.!!

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-08-22 19:20:38.605 ERROR 6720 --- [ampleApp.main()] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.spring.sample.SampleApp.main(SampleApp.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 33 common frames omitted

[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.spring.sample.SampleApp.main(SampleApp.java:27)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 33 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.886 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-22T19:20:38-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/451M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update**
My project had dependencies on both spring-data-cassandra and spring-boot-starter-jpa. When i removed dependency on spring-boot-started-jpa, everything worked fine. The application comes up and i am able to read and write from the cassandra cluster.

Comment: You may be interested by [this pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/2214) there is no official auto-configuration support for Cassandra yet. Maybe you could look in that PR to see what's wrong with your config?

Comment: Take a look at your dependencies and make sure you aren't including JPA (I see some references to springdata.jpa in your imports).  I looks like Spring Boot's autowiring is triggering on that because it is in your classpath.  You might also try disabling the datasource autoconfig (@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}))

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll - Thanks for the reply. I already checked this out. The cassandra fix is not available yet.

Comment: @ShawnSherwood - Thanks for the reply. I already disabled DataSource autoconfig (please see above). I get a different error if i dont specify a dependency on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. And moreover, if i want to have an other sql database along with cassandra, having dependency on  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is must.

Comment: If you really want to have different data sources, then you'll really want the JPA DataSource config back in there.  It was not obvious from the source you've provided that you needed that.  I would argue taking a step back and making sure you have the non-Cassandra datasource wired up properly and then add Cassandra (or go the other way and remove JPA entirely and verify the Cassandra config).  Generally, my suggestion is to work on one config at a time.

Comment: @ShawnSherwood - Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion. By removing the dependency on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra just worked fine. I am able to read/write from the cassandra database. For now, being able to access cassandra is enough for me. Just curious on why it is failing when i include spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Doesn't spring-boot recognize cassandra as valid datasource.?? if that is the case, will the metrics/health of datasource api's provided by spring-boot-actuator work for cassandra.??

Comment: @NaveenChandra - JPA is for traditional relational SQL databases.  Cassandra is NoSQL and does not have a javax.sql.DataSource implementation.  There is no real standardization in the NoSQL world (yet), so each database will likely have its own special configuration mechanism.  Spring Data is trying to abstract this the best it can but you can see its not always obvious what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and this fixed it for me:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Gosling-RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```